# Status Item NSPopover won't display if app is fullscreened

Tags: swift, macos, fullscreen, nsstatusitem

I'm having trouble getting a NSPopover for my app to display when an app is full screened. It doesn't matter if the app is mine or another.[image: :(]

Image below is the popover displaying out of fullscreen, fullscreen it just flickers with nothing showing.

Comment: What is the NSPopover''s behavior property set to?

Comment: Transient, what should it be set to?

Comment: Not sure exactly. But maybe you should try playing with that setting. Seems related.